# Markdown code styling - colour whole section instead of just text

Tags: css, markdown

I'm using [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) to create simple Markdown editor and I want to add some additional styling to code blocks.
This is how it looks like now
[image]

And this is my current code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card markdown-wrapper">
    <textarea class="editor" v-model="input" @input="update"></textarea>
    <div class="preview" v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.markdown-wrapper {
  min-height: 65vw;
  display: flex;
}

.editor {
  border: none;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 50%;
}

.preview {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
}

code {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

As you probably imagine, that's now that I'm trying to achieve. I would like to add some padding, border and colour whole code area, not only text, I'd like it to look a bit more like this, but to be honest, whatever I try - it doesn't work... any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`<code>` is an inline level element. An inline element does not start on a new line and **only takes up as much width as necessary**.

You need to change the display of `<code>` to `inline-block`.

---

#### Inline-block

> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with
> surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much
> like a replaced element would). [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
code {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

---

#### Example

```js
const c = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = marked(c);
```

```css
code {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

````html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  ```
  var s = "Code Example";
  alert(s);
  ```
</div>
````

Answer (score 0):

Like most markdown processors, Marked renders code blocks as `<code>` tags *inside a `<pre>` tag*. I think you should be styling the `<pre>` tag, e.g. something like this:

```css
pre {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Of course, if you are using `<pre>` tags elsewhere you might have to get more specific with your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Add some custom [css](/questions/tagged/css) to the `<pre><code></code></pre>` elements:

```js
const c = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = marked(c);
```

```css
pre {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

````html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  ## Marked.js
  ### CodeBlock styling Example
  ```
  const test = 123;
  console.log(test);
  ```
  <sub>[Marked.js Github](https://github.com/markedjs/marked)</sub>
  
</div>
````